# Return a simple integer value usign HTTPPOST method using .nep core web api

Tags: c#, webapi

Actually it is basic but altougt i researced, i couldn't find any example about that. I want to have a api controller which calculate and it must be using HttpPost and i should include an int parameter. Afterward, i want to display my in value on the screen.

These is how i wrote my code and first of all i have no such experience on web api. I mean i know crud but i dont know how can i define a post method which takes parameter and return this parameter on web.

```
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
       [HttpPost("{value}")]
       public int Pi(int value)
       {
           return value;
       }
    }
```

But when i go to api/values/Pi/5... i want to see this value on screen. Please can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Add Routing on Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("{value}")]
    public int Pi(int value)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank i tried but it doesn't return. I also tried [Route("api/[controller]/[action]/{value?}")] bu it is over again.

Comment: http://localhost:50212/api/Values/Pi/5  try it from postman and select Post method not get

Comment: Thanks it is done on postman. How can i send multiple parameter for a matematichal process?

Comment: like this 
    public int Pi ([FromBody] List<int> Numbers)
    {
     return Number[0] +Number[1]
    }

Comment: Thank u so much. You mad my day. :)